# Update statement conflicted with FK while updating in generic repository .net core web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, repository-pattern

Basically when calling Put method from controller and trying to update properties im getting conflict from Db.

[image]

Using repository pattern with unit of work.

Car model -

```
public class Car : BaseModel 
    {
        public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
        public Guid ManufacturerId { get; set; }
        public Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }
        public Guid ManufacturerModelId { get; set; }
        public ManufacturerModel ManufacturerModel { get; set; }
        public DateTime ManufactureDate { get; set; }
        public string Engine { get; set; }
        public Guid FuelTypeId { get; set; }
        public FuelType FuelType { get; set; }
        public Guid FrameTypeId { get; set; }
        public FrameType FrameType { get; set; }
        public Guid ColorId { get; set; }
        public Color Color { get; set; }
        public Guid TransmissionId { get; set; }
        public Transmission Transmission { get; set; }
        public Guid DefectsId { get; set; }
        public Defects Defects { get; set; }
        public Guid SteeringWheelPosId { get; set; }
        public SteeringWheelPos SteeringWheelPos { get; set; }
        public Doors Doors { get; set; }
        public int Seats { get; set; }
        public DateTime VehicleInspection { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
```

BaseModel class

```
public class BaseModel : IBaseModel
    {

        public BaseModel()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
        }
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    }
```

put method (im using cqrs here, and controller already passes carDto to method)

```
 public async Task<Unit> Handle(Command request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                if(request.obj == null)
                {
                    throw new StatusCodeException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Object is empty");
                }
                var DbEntry = uow.carRepository.GetById(request.Id);
                if (DbEntry == null)
                {
                    throw new StatusCodeException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "was not found in database", request.Id);
                }
                request.obj.Id = request.Id;
                var s = uow.Mapper.Map(request.obj, DbEntry);
                uow.carRepository.Update(s);
                uow.Commit();
                return Unit.Value;
            }

//Update method in generic repository class 


public void Update(T obj)
        {        
            context.Attach(obj);
            context.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
```

I can't find where i do something wrong. Checked with breakpoints, data is correct everywhere. getting error when calling uow to commit changes. Thank you. Looking forward.

Comment: First, post the *error text*, not a link to the error image. Second, don't use the "generic" repository **anti**pattern to begin with. A DbSet is *already* a repository, a DbContet is *already* a Unit-of-Work. EF Core is a *higher-level* abstraction than a repository too. BTW CQRS doesn't mean you need something called `request`. It means that *modification* operations and *query* operations should be separate. It means that the "repositories" used for commands and queries are different too

Comment: You should check Gunnar Peipman's [No need for repositories and unit of work with Entity Framework Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/) and Oren Eini's [Repository is the New Singleton](https://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton). The second article is by the maintainer of NHibernate at the time, yes, it's from 2009, which shows for how long people knew that Repository shouldn't be used with ORMs.

Comment: Where does this error occur, what objects are involved? Adding a generic repository and that handler means it's now impossible to understand what is being updated - a car with related defects? A defect pointing to a car? Was this in response to a POST, a PUT? If the `Id` gets a default GUID value, EF Core no longer knows whether it's a new instance that should be inserted, or an existing instance that needs updating. *Attaching* it (that's what "Update" does, it doesn't update anything) isn't enough

Comment: The `DefectId` property is a `Guid` which means it has a zero GUID value if there's no related defect. EF Core will try to store a zero GUID to the database, resulting in an FK violation. You can modify this behaviour through the EF DbContext's configuration (eg specify that `Defects` isn't required) and making `DefectId` a `Guid?`

Comment: Another problem is that GUIDs are a terrible choice for a key. The values are essentially random which means *new* items have to be added in the middle of a table, leading to serious fragmentation. If you *really really* need them, you need to specify a sequential GUID algorithm to create them. The best place to do so is in the database, as a default constraint for the PK field

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this error happens is because, your foreign key 'DefectId' in 'Car' probably has value 0.

When entity framework core encounters value 0 for foreign key, it throws this kind of error, because it cannot insert foreign value 0 which is the primary key of some object. Obviously, primary keys cannot be value 0.

Hope, this answers to your question.